# Is it posiible to add html in clipboard data?

Tags: javascript, html

When you select some elements on the webpage by mouse and then paste it in new email (for example in gmail) you still see html elements. But when I add html code to clipboard from js I still see html code after pasting. Is there any way to add some html code from js and see generated elements after pasting?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible because of the way gmail handles this (the right way). Just imagine if you were able to send javascript tags to anyone with codes that would send cookie info back to you. This is called escaping html and google (and everyone else who does it does it right). Cheers